# Track object position during an animation using python script

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a simple script that displays the position of a falling cube on a custom panel. I want it to update the panel throughout the animation.  Here is the code so far:

```
import bpy

class MocapPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Display Data"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_current
    print(frame)
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)

    obj = context.object

    body = bpy.data.objects[obj.name]
    row = layout.row()
    row.label(text="MocapData", icon='WORLD_DATA')
    pos = body.location.z

    row = layout.row()
    row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)
    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(obj, "name")
    row = layout.row()
    row.label(text="object position is " + str(pos))
    print(pos)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MocapPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MocapPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

all it does is display the start position at the moment. Can I get it to update with every frame?

Comment: Get rid of the scene.frame_set() .. it's already at that frame anyway... You can't update blender object properties in a panels draw method.

Comment: okay, was just checking to see if maybe the problem was that maybe it was not set to the right frame. cheers.

Answer (score 2):

[`Object.matrix_world.to_translation()`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html?highlight=to_translation#mathutils.Matrix.to_translation) gives you a global (visual) location of the object.  The frame change handler makes the panel "hot" and update on every frame change.

```
import bpy

class MocapPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Display Data"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object is not None

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object
        pos = obj.matrix_world.to_translation()

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="object position z is %.2f" % pos.z)

def prop_redraw(scene):
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'PROPERTIES':
            if area.spaces.active.context == 'OBJECT':
                area.tag_redraw()

def register():
    #clear handlers for testing
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()
    # add a handler to make the area "live" without mouse over
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(prop_redraw)

    bpy.utils.register_class(MocapPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```